# jquery $(this) object missing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop, object

I have a problem with jQuery's `$(this)` object and make me miss the `this` element
in code :

```
 $('.star').click(function (){
    var id   = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('rating')[1];
    var vote = $(this).index() + 1;
    var ThisStar = $(this);

    alert(ThisStar.parent().html())

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  EXECUTION_URL + 'ajax/rate.php',
        data: {'article' :id  ,'rate': vote},
        success:function(data,tt,ff){
            alert(ThisStar.parent().html())
        }
  });
```

the first alert fire : the true contents of the parents of the clicked node
the second alert fire : null !!!!
why it have been changed into the ajax ? or from another reason  ? please tell me a good solution for this issue

**ok actually i checked my code that there is two lines after the ajax function that delete the stored node in the `this` object and because of the ajax function is asynchronous function the two lines executed before the code inside the success function >> thanks for all**

Comment: Nitpick: doing $(this) over and over again is bad for performance. Store it in a variable or use chaining.

Comment: I suspect you're not telling us the whole story.  What happens if you just alert `ThisStar`, instead of the `.parent().html()` ?

Comment: try a `console.log(ThisStar);` inside ajax. Is it an object?

Comment: some part of code may be missing..

Comment: just alert ThisStar in the two states fire :[object Object]

Comment: do no alert it, use `console.log(ThisStar)`

Comment: try adding a semicolon at the end of the first and second alert statements

Comment: @ParvSharma whatever his problem is, it's not missing semicolons.

Comment: @MihaiIorga i tried console.log(ThisStar):
out from ajax in console it shows [div.star] and when mu cursor on it it show in 'title' the full path of this node
in ajax it shows only in 'title' /div

Comment: @CodeJack you are right ... after two lines there is 
$(this).parent().removeAttr("id");
$(this).parent().html(" ");

when i commented it it works find .. but now i don't under stand how the lines after ajax line excecuted before the success of ajax function .... however thank you :)

Comment: now because you are new here.. i think you should either delete your question or update it with the code and add an ans and 2 days after mark it as an ans.. dont just leave it like this

Comment: @ParvSharma ok thank you for your advice .. just seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, **[check the proof](http://jsfiddle.net/PcLD6/)**. The only difference would be this:

```
success:function(data,tt,ff){
    alert(ThisStar.parent().html())
}
```

vs.

```
success:function(data,tt,ff){
    alert(ThisStar.parent().html())
}});
```